# How to use reducer of one component in another component that renders list of such components

Tags: reactjs, redux, lazy-loading

I have a React component that shows one item per page. It has it's own reducer as well. I want to find the way how to use this component and reducer in another component that renders all items with unlimited scrolling. I dont want to break the DRY principle. This reducer have many action cases.

For example, i have a news feed and i want to repost the whole page with all content and fuctionality to this feed.

```
const onelessonReducer = (state=initialtate, action) => {
    let stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_LESSON:

        case ACTION1:

        case ACTION2:

        case ACTION3
}}:


import Lesson from './Lesson'
let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
        data: state.lesson
    }
}


const LessonContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {getTestThunkCreator,addBreak, removeBreak,
    selectGap,addGap,selectQuiz})(Lesson)

export default LessonContainer
```

I wanna use the logic of onelessonReducer in the component like that:

```
const AllLessonsInOnePage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{id.less}
            {props.data.lessons.map((tag, index) => 
            <Lesson 
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AllLessonsInOnePage
```

Comment: I have no idea, what's "component's own reducer", so sharing some relevant code would, probably, shed some light.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I've added some code to clarify my question

Comment: I'm still not sure I understood the question, but it looks to me that you're missing the concept behind Redux. Reducers are not attributed to any particular component, they respond to user interactions (or other events anywhere in the app, for that matter) triggering state updates through dispatching corresponding actions. Consequently, all the components, depending on global state, respond to state updates. So, to achieve same state updates from different components, you just dispatch same action and to reflect same properties of the state in different components, you `connect` them.

Comment: Just a side note - using combination of `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` for deep copying the object is not a good idea for many reasons. To make your redux code not to look _legacy_, you may opt for `useDispatch()` and `useSelector()` hooks (in combination with reselect library).

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov The lesson component has structure: `<Lesson><Exersise1><Exersise2><Exersise3>....<ExersiseN></Lesson>.  I started to develope it from the bottom level. Every Exersise have pretty complex logic. The lesson reducer manages the state of the Lesson component.  I have another reducer for a list of lesson page.  It is the simple list of lesson names that lead to the lesson page. I've ocasionally got an idea to develop lessons feed like in facebook wall that combine all lessons with content. And i dont have an idea how to do that.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov I want to have two diffrent components that is managed by one reducer.

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov I am afraid of too deep nesting of my exersize state: {feed: [{lesson1: [{exersize1: [string1, string2]}], {exersize2: [string1, string2]}]}, {lesson2}]}.